# Fancybox wont work when uploaded to server?

Tags: fancybox

I've been working on this website for a friend for few days now. Today, we finally uploaded it, but fancybox wont work. It works fine when I test it locally, but when its uploaded it wont work.

Here is the site: *********** (works now)

Let me know what exactly I did wrong. I'm still new at web design, and learning..

Edit: Go to buy now section, and click order button. Fancybox should popup where user can enter their details.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct link to your fancybox.css

http://solo-beast.com/fancyBox/source/jquery.fancybox.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

You seem to have a "jquery." in the file name for a css file.

Comment: Ok. That helped. But now it just opens the iframe src in current window, instead of fancybox?

Comment: You now have issues that you didn't have before:
GET http://solo-beast.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js 
solo-beast.com/:32
 GET http://solo-beast.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js 
solo-beast.com/:31

Comment: All I did was add capitalization to fancyBox.  ._.

Comment: If you use google chrome inspector and look at the console tab, it will show you the errors on the page.

Comment: Hah, im dumb. Forgot to change capitalization everywhere. Thanks for the tip btw on chrome inspector thingy.